# using extern keyword for user defined types in c++

Tags: c++, extern

I want to use `extern` keyword for user defined types. This means I've declared object in one file and defined it in other file. I've read that extern keyword is used to declare the variable without defining it. extern keyword is useful when program is split into multiple source files and global variable needs to be used by each of them. Please correct me If I am wrong somewhere.

Here is the programs I've written but unfortunately I am doing something wrong or missing something so I am getting compiler errors.

Prog1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
class test
{
     public:
     void fun();
};
void test::fun()
{
    cout<<"fun() in test\n";
}
test t;
```

Prog2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
extern test t;
int main()
{
    t.fun();
}
```

Now when I compile these 2 using

`g++ -o prog1.cpp prog2.cpp`

compiler gives me following errors in prog2.cpp

```
error: 'test' does not name a type

error:  't' was not declared in this scope
```

Please help me to know what I've done wrong here.

Comment: `extern` tells the compiler that the definition of `t` is somewhere else, but the compiler still needs the defintiion of `test`, as you're using `t.fun()` to *compile* `Prog2.cpp`.

Comment: Why have you got a burning desire to use `extern`?

Comment: @Nawaz: so what's going really wrong here?

Comment: Put the *extern* keyword in the *header*, not the *cpp* file. It is the job of the  *header* to tell the compiler there is an *externally defined* object somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extern` tells the compiler that the definition of `t` is somewhere else, but the compiler still needs the defintiion of `test`, as you're using `t.fun()` to *compile* `Prog2.cpp`.

So the solution is, write `test.h` where you define the class, and then define `test t` in `Prog2.cpp` as usual. Include `test.h` in your `Prog2.cpp` so that it may know the definition of `test`. Then build it.

**test.h:**

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class test  //definition of test
{
     public:
     void fun()
     {
        cout<<"fun() in test\n";
     }
};
```

**Prog1.cpp:**

```
#include "test.h"

test t;  //definition of t
```

**Prog2.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

#include "test.h"

using std::cout;

extern test t; //the definition of t is somewhere else (in some .o)
               //and the definition of test is in test.h
int main()
{
    t.fun();
}
```

Now your code should compile and link.

Note that the definition of `t` is needed by the linker at link-time, so it will search for it in other `.o` files, but the definition of `test` is needed by the compiler, at compile-time.

Now it should be obvious that you can put the `extern test t;` in the header itself so that you dont have to write it in every `.cpp` file where you want to use the object defined in `Prog1.cpp` file (which is turned into `Prog1.o` by the compiler).

Comment: Why it is necessary to create header file? Isn't it possible without using header file?

Comment: That is a correct approach. The `Prog2.cpp` needs to know that `t` which is of type `test` has a member function called `fun`. Note that when the compiler compiles `Prog2.cpp` into `Prog2.o`, it doesn't know anything about other `.cpp` files. It is the linker which links all `.o` generated from `.cpp` files.

Comment: @meet: Added more elaboration (the last line).

Comment: I don't know why but the solution given by you still not working for me. Linker complains & says that undefined reference to t error id returned 1 exit status. other surprising thing is that prog1.cpp file automatically gets deleted when I compile this? Why? What's still going wrong for me?

Comment: @meet: You must be doing something different than what I've explained in my answer.

Comment: @meet: How do you compile your code now? You have to do this: `g++ Prog1.cpp Prog2.cpp`.. NOT anything else. (you can optionally provide `-o xyz`, I usually use `-o run.lab` , or `-o run.test`.

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake I forgot to mention new name for exe file when using -o option. I wrote wrongly g++ -o Prog1.cpp Prog2.cpp. again, thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

Put the *extern* keyword in the *header*, not the *cpp* file. It is the job of the  *header* to tell the compiler there is an *externally defined* object somewhere.

> For example:

**program.h** (mostly declarations)

```
struct UserDefinedType
{
    void do_stuff();
};

// declare your global object in the header
// so that the compiler knows its name when
// compiling sources that can not otherwise see
// the object
extern UserDefinedType global_udt;
```

**program.cpp** (mostly definitions)

```
#include "program.h"

// define the member functions here
void UserDefinedType::do_stuff()
{
}

// define the global object here
UserDefinedType global_udt;
```

**main.cpp** (use the *definitions* that have been *declared* in the header)

```
#include "program.h" // tells the compiler about global_udt

int main()
{
    // call the global object that is defined
    // in a different source file (program.cpp)
    global_udt.do_stuff();
}
```

**NOTE:** If we didn't *declare* the object `global_udt` in the *header* file then **main.cpp** would not know of its existence and the compiler would complain if we tried to use it.

So the *header* needs to only *declare* the object and not *define* it hence the *extern* keyword is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a variable declared outside the class scope is a variable with external linkage(if not explicitly used the *static* keyword) or with internal linkage(if the *static* keyword is put in the left of the variable type), *extern* is necessary if you want to use it in multiple files.

Suppose this file is called **MyVariable.h**

```
int myNumber = 0; // Initialization of the variable myNumber, external linkage
static int myStaticNumber; // Initialization of the variable myStaticNumber, internal linkage(only the file in which it's declared)
```

And this file is **OtherFile.cpp**

```
extern int myNumber; // Not a initialization because it's already initialized in another file, works fine
extern int myStaticNumber; // ERROR, this variable has internal linkage!!
```

You may wonder why myStaticNumber was initialized and not just declared, that occurs because *static* variables are initialized to their default values by default.